# Jquery Image Load in IE

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to use a script, which works fine in Chrome and firefox but Jams In IE.

See here
http://www.micahcarrick.com/code/jquery-image-swap/index.html

Why does it not Work in Ie, any idea's anyone?

Comment: It only breaks after the image is loaded from cache, right?

Comment: Which IE version? I'm looking at it in IE9 and it looks like it's working.

Comment: Have set it up on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yPme4/

Answer (score 6):

In at least some versions of IE, you have to register the load event BEFORE you set the `.src` property because if the image is in the cache, the load event will fire immediately right when you set `.src` and thus you will miss it if you haven't already set the `.load` event handler.

In the jsFiddle code, it would need to be this (also simplified it a bit):

```
var url = this.href;
$('<img />').load(function() {
    $('#imageWrap').css('background-image', 'none');
    $('#mainImage').attr('src', url).fadeIn();
}).attr('src', url);
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vEVVG/

Comment: Just pasted that into JSFiddle and it made no difference

Comment: u need to change the i.attr('src') to this.href to get it to work, cant edit the answer yet so it in this comment. http://jsfiddle.net/yPme4/2/

Comment: @Dampsquid - OK, changes made, to make it work in the jsFiddle.  I was just trying to illustrate where they have to put the setting of the `.src`.  That's the main point here, but now it's been simplified and works too in my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vEVVG/.

Comment: yep you identifed the fault, its one i didnt know about so learned something new myself, very new to all this web dev and not used JQuery but have used mootools and its pretty similar.